# struct sockaddr_in member byte order for bind()

Tags: c, sockets, endianness

I'm learning socket programming and am confused by what I feel is inconsistent use of `htons()` and family of functions in my learning material. I'm currently reading [this site](http://alas.matf.bg.ac.rs/manuals/lspe/snode=27.html) which has the following code segment:

```
001 1:       struct sockaddr_in adr_inet;
002 2:       int adr_len;
003 3:
004 4:       memset(&adr_inet,0,sizeof adr_inet);
005 5:
006 6:       adr_inet.sin_family = AF_INET;
007 7:       adr_inet.sin_port = ntohs(0);
008 8:       adr_inet.sin_addr.s_addr = ntohl(INADDR_ANY);
009 9:       adr_len = sizeof adr_inet;
```

A subsequent example further down at the same noted site has the following code segment:

```
030 30:      struct sockaddr_in adr_inet;/* AF_INET */
...
042 42:      /* Create an AF_INET address */
043 43:      memset(&adr_inet,0,sizeof adr_inet);
044 44:
045 45:      adr_inet.sin_family = AF_INET;
046 46:      adr_inet.sin_port = htons(9000);
047 47:      memcpy(&adr_inet.sin_addr.s_addr,IPno,4);
048 48:      len_inet = sizeof adr_inet;
049 49:
050 50:      /* Now bind the address to the socket */
051 51:      z = bind(sck_inet,
052 52:          (struct sockaddr *)&adr_inet,
053 53:          len_inet);
```

**Question**:

Why is `ntohs()` used on `adr_inet.sin_port` in the first instance, but `htons()` in the second?

**Question**:

Why is neither `ntohs()` nor `htons()` used on `adr_inet.sin_family`?

The noted site doesn't explain *why* `ntohs()` or `htons()` are used in their respective examples; it only says to "note the use of" said functions.

I understand endianness and that network byte order is big-endian order. My questions is more about when do you want a `struct sockaddr_in`'s members in network vs. host byte order? In the second code example, `.sin_port` is set to network byte order before being passed to `bind()`. I can see the case for passing data to this function in either network or host byte order: `bind()` is a "network-related" function, so maybe it needs its data in network byte order; on the other hand `bind()` is executed on the host, so why shouldn't accept data in host byte order?

Comment: (( I advice you to read about [`getaddrinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) to write more modern C ))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is ntohs() used on adr_inet.sin_port in the first instance, but htons() in the second?

The first is a mistake, but in practice works anyway.

Nowadays practically all machines use 8-bit bytes and either consistent big-endian or consistent little-endian formats. On the former both `hton[sl]` and `ntoh[sl]` are no-ops; on the latter *both* reverse the byte order, and thus actually do the same thing even though their intended semantics are different. Thus using the wrong one still works on all systems you're likely to run a program on.

Back when the socket API was designed this wasn't always the case; for example the then-popular PDP-11 somewhat infamously used ['middle-endian'](http://catb.org/jargon/html/M/middle-endian.html) (!) aka 'NUXI' order for 32-bit.

> Why is neither ntohs() nor htons() used on adr_inet.sin_family?

Again in ancient times the Internet Protocol stack was only one of several (up to a dozen or so) competing network technologies. The `family` field distinguishes different types of `sockaddr_*` structures for these different protocols, which did not all follow the Internet 'rule' for big-endian, at least not consistently. As there was no universal network representation for `family` they just left it in host order -- which is usually more convenient for host software.

Nowadays in practice nobody uses any families but INET, INET6, and sometimes UNIX -- and the latter can be replaced by using named pipes in the filesystem which is usually at least as good.

Comment: Ah: I misunderstood `hton[sl]` and `ntoh[sl]`: I thought they _guaranteed_ the output was network or host byte ordered, respectively. But when I think about it, that'd be impossible to implement, so the only thing those functions can do is make an architecture-dependent decision whether to be a no-op or a byteswap.

Comment: UNIX sockets are in no way replaceable by named pipes. First of all, with one named pipe there can be only one named connection. And AFAIK you cannot send ancillary data (file descriptors) over named pipes.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is neither `ntohs()` nor `htons()` used on `adr_inet.sin_family`?

`adr_inet.sin_family` is initialized to the value of `AF_INET`.  This is defined in `bits/socket.h` (which is called by `netinet/in.h` in your example) as:

```
#define PF_INET     2   /* IP protocol family.  */
```

and then,

```
#define AF_INET     PF_INET
```

So `AF_INET` is just a way for the program to identify the associated socket as a TCP/IP connection.  It won't actually hold the value of an IPv4 address itself, so there's no need to perform an endian conversion on it.

Also, note that in newer iterations of C, `netinet/in.h` has a comment that states the following:

```
/* Functions to convert between host and network byte order.

   Please note that these functions normally take `unsigned long int' or
`unsigned short int' values as arguments and also return them.  But
this was a short-sighted decision since on different systems the types
may have different representations but the values are always the same.  */ 
extern uint32_t ntohl (uint32_t __netlong) __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__));
extern uint16_t ntohs (uint16_t __netshort)
        __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__));
extern uint32_t htonl (uint32_t __hostlong)
        __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__));
extern uint16_t htons (uint16_t __hostshort)
        __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__));
```

Whereas the website you're referencing cites the older use of `unsigned long` and `unsigned short`
datatypes for the conversion functions.  So there's a chance you may encounter issues running code from that site if
you're using a newer version of C.

Comment: Even on a system with 64-bit `unsigned long`, if you only use the bottom 32 bits, storing to or from a `uint32_t` will work.  At worst, you might get a warning about a narrowing implicit conversion.

Comment: Yeah, you're exactly right.  I should have been more clear about that in my post.  Still, the use of those datatypes might be considered a little out of date in this context.  Or "short-sighted" as the author wrote in that comment above the newer conversion prototypes.

Comment: Yes. The historical Unix API created a lot of problems by assuming that `unsigned long` was the right length to hold a pointer, a file offset, the number of seconds since 1970, etc.—and also that it was exactly 32 bits long. These days, most compilers let you choose which one of those assumptions should be correct and POSIX guarantees that there is a compiler flag to make `long` wide enough to hold any of those types. But it’s better to use the type you really mean.

Comment: Oh, side note for anyone who comes by later: to get the modern definitions, set a feature-test macro before including the system headers, such as `_XOPEN_SOURCE` and/or `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` on POSIX/Linux/glibc, or `_WIN32_WINNT` on Windows.  These change which declarations are active in the header files.