# What byte order does recvfrom() save src_addr as?

Tags: c, linux, recvfrom

`size_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags, struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen)`

In what byte order is the `src_addr` argument written? Network or host? I couldn't find this in the `recvfrom` man page or a search through google and SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [struct sockaddr\_in member byte order for bind()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274977/struct-sockaddr-in-member-byte-order-for-bind)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the socket is an IPv4 or IPv6 socket, the host and port stored in `src_addr` will be in network byte order.

This is documented in the [man page for IPv4 (`man 7 ip`)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) as follows:

> Address format
>
> An IP socket address is defined as a combination of an IP interface
>   address and a 16-bit port number.  The basic IP protocol does not
>   supply port numbers, they are implemented by higher level protocols
>   like udp(7) and tcp(7).  On raw sockets sin_port is set to the IP
>   protocol.
>
> ```
>    struct sockaddr_in {
>        sa_family_t    sin_family; /* address family: AF_INET */
>        in_port_t      sin_port;   /* port in network byte order */
>        struct in_addr sin_addr;   /* internet address */
>    };
>
>    /* Internet address. */
>    struct in_addr {
>        uint32_t       s_addr;     /* address in network byte order */
>    };
> ```
>
> `sin_family` is always set to `AF_INET`.  This is required; in Linux
>   2.2    most networking functions return `EINVAL` when this setting is missing.    **`sin_port` contains the port in network byte order.**  The
>   port numbers    below 1024 are called privileged ports (or sometimes:
>   reserved    ports).  Only a privileged process (on Linux: a process
>   that has the    CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE capability in the user namespace
>   governing its    network namespace) may bind(2) to these sockets. 
>   Note that the raw    IPv4 protocol as such has no concept of a port,
>   they are implemented    only by higher protocols like tcp(7) and
>   udp(7).
>
> **`sin_addr` is the IP host address.  The `s_addr` member of struct
>   `in_addr`    contains the host interface address in network byte order.** 
>   `in_addr`    should be assigned one of the `INADDR_*` values (e.g.,
>   `INADDR_LOOPBACK`)    using htonl(3) or set using the inet_aton(3),
>   inet_addr(3),    inet_makeaddr(3) library functions or directly with
>   the name resolver    (see gethostbyname(3)).

The ipv6 man page has similar wording.

So when reading the port number, use `ntohs` to extract it.  When reading the address, use `inet_ntop` to convert it to text form.

Comment: Thank you - do you know where I could have looked that up? I was a bit surprised it wasn't in the man page. Or is that assumed "domain  knowledge" for network programming?

Comment: @StoneThrow [man 7 ip](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) and [man 7 ipv6](https://linux.die.net/man/7/ipv6) contain general information about using IPv4 and IPv6 sockets respectively.

Comment: @bishop: You are lining the outedated version 6. The current version 7 is here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netinet_in.h.html